# Can I read bigtable records with cbt by time?

Tags: bigtable, cbt

I want to read the last (latest) records written to bigtable with cbt.  The docs don't mention which order `cbt read` reads records in, however.  I don't know what the row key(s) would be.

Is there a way to read records with cbt by insertion time?

Update:

Here is what I see when reading a table:

```
cbt read table_name count=10 | grep processedTime
2021/12/17 09:20:42 -creds flag unset, will use gcloud credential
  general:processedTime                    @ 2021/06/29-14:40:04.028000
  general:processedTime                    @ 2021/06/17-12:32:04.055000
  general:processedTime                    @ 2021/06/17-12:32:40.032000
  general:processedTime                    @ 2021/06/17-12:32:43.047000
  general:processedTime                    @ 2021/06/10-18:45:53.495000
  general:processedTime                    @ 2021/06/17-12:31:28.772000
  general:processedTime                    @ 2021/06/17-12:30:41.205000
  general:processedTime                    @ 2021/06/17-12:30:33.960000
  general:processedTime                    @ 2021/06/29-14:40:17.811000
  general:processedTime                    @ 2021/06/17-12:32:06.795000
  general:processedTime                    @ 2021/06/17-12:31:49.202000
```

The cbt read does not give results in order by time.

Is there a way to get cbt read to order the results by time?

Answer (score -1):

Currently, `cbt` tool may not guarantee to return data in sorted order especially when there's a lot of data. It is possible that Bigtable takes time to organize it.  However based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reads#overview), Bigtable read requests in the order in which they are stored. Therefore, the latest record would have to be at the top.

Referencing the 2 testing scenarios I did. First is to insert data without specifying the timestamp, second is to insert data specifying the timestamp. Either way, I got the data in descending order based on timestamp.

Timestamp not specified:

```
@cloudshell:~ $ cbt set my-table r1 cf1:c1=val5
2021/12/15 10:51:52 -creds flag unset, will use gcloud credential
@cloudshell:~ $ cbt read my-table
2021/12/15 10:52:07 -creds flag unset, will use gcloud credential
----------------------------------------
r1
  cf1:c1                                   @ 2021/12/15-10:51:59.760000
    "val5"
  cf1:c1                                   @ 2021/12/15-10:26:00.471000
    "val4"
  cf1:c1                                   @ 2021/12/15-10:25:26.863000
    "val3"
  cf1:c1                                   @ 2021/12/15-10:24:58.021000
    "val2"
  cf1:c1                                   @ 2021/12/15-10:24:52.259000
    "val1"
@cloudshell:~ $ cbt read my-table cells-per-column=1
2021/12/15 10:52:17 -creds flag unset, will use gcloud credential
----------------------------------------
r1
  cf1:c1                                   @ 2021/12/15-10:51:59.760000
    "val5"
```

Timestamp specified:

[image]

Your use case might not be entirely covered by [CBT tool](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/tree/main/bigtable/cmd/cbt). My suggestion is to file a feature request to their GitHub repo. No guarantees when or if it will ever be implemented.

Comment: `Read requests to Bigtable stream back the contents of the requested rows in key order, meaning they are returned in the order in which they are stored.`  Insertion order is different.  The rows are not returned based on insertion time.

Comment: @DeanSchulze Hi OP, check this testing where timestamp is specified upon insertion. As you can see, Bigtable reads timestamps in decreasing value. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkrQf.png
Can you describe what you'd like to see in this situation?

Comment: @DeanSchulze please check my answer. I updated it with additional information.

Comment: I updated my question with output from cbt read.  The results are not in order by time.

Comment: @DeanSchulze please see my updated answer.